# error: replacement has 0 rows, data has 1186

Tags: r, date, replace, runtime-error, lubridate

```
data <- read_csv(files, show_col_types = FALSE, skip=7)
   library(lubridate) 
  temp<- data.frame(data$Date)
ymd <- ymd(temp$Date) 
dmy <- dmy(temp$Date) 
ymd[is.na(ymd)] <- dmy[is.na(ymd)]
temp$Date <- ymd
data$Date<-temp
```

Im getting a runtime error:-  Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Date", value = numeric(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 1186. Im trying to make a new temporary df to store dates in to parse it to a readable date format. Please help someone ?

Comment: Can you provide `dput(head(data)` (i.e. right after you read in the file in the `read_csv()` line?

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(17539, 17570, 17598, 17629, 
17659, 17690), class = "Date"), `Minimum temperature` = c(7.6, 
-3.8, -3.6, 3.7, -1, 1.2), `Maximum temperature` = c(15.4, 14.3, 
19.5, 12.8, 15, 13.7), `Rainfall (mm)` = c(0, 0, 0, 13.8, 0, 
0), `Evaporation (mm)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Sunshine (hours)` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Direction of maximum wind gust` = c("NW", 
"NNW", "NW", "NNW", "NW", "NW"), `Speed of maximum wind gust (km/h)` = c(54, 
26, 72, 54, 43, 61), `Time of maximum wind gust` = structure(c(5880, 
44580, 75360, 17400, 44340, 38880),

Comment: Edit the question and paste the output there.

Comment: @ShaneYep It looks like you're reading in multiple files with `read_csv`. As requested by @Dave2e, please edit your original post with the output instead of adding as comment. Your data `structure` is incomplete above and appears cut off...

Comment: Assuming read_csv is working, look at `names(temp)`. I'd wager it returns "data.Date" rather than "Date", meaning `ymd` and downstream object are empty.

Comment: Thanks guys, there was an error in the source files. So all solutions was resolved